# PHP Syntax for multiple checks in one if statement

Tags: php

I'm making a shoppingcart.php file for a project, which is fed information by another file called "catalog.php" in the same project. The thing I'm stuck on is the if statement inside of a while loop (which is supposed to loop through incoming form data from catalog.php). For some reason, it doesn't like this:

```
//Loop through each form field (this page is called from catalog.php):        

    //If form field’s value (product quantity) is a positive number
//(nonzero), is NOT the submit button, AND the remove checkbox for 
//removing this product has NOT been checked (do these checks in one
    //condition):        
    while (list($productID,$qty) = each($_POST)){
        if(($qty > 0) && (type != submit) && (checkbox != isset())){

        }            
    }
```

What's wrong with my if statement?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Are there variables without `$`???

Comment: (type != submit) && (checkbox != isset()) what is it?

Comment: @MarcelGwerder No. But constants don't start with a `$` sign.

Comment: @Jocelyn I know but it doesn't look like this should be constants.

Comment: But "$qty" is not a constant. It's a variable for the quantity of  products (how many of each) of a certain product in the user's shopping cart.

Comment: @MarcelGwerder Yes, here they are certainly variables with a typo.

Answer (score 2):

You are using php's [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) incorrectly. `isset()` requires a variable argument and "[determines] if a variable is set and is not NULL".

Try this:

```
if (($qty > 0) && ($type != 'submit') && !isset($checkbox)) {

}
```

Comment: The error tool tip says, " Syntax error: expected: ::,( ". Am I supposed to have a "::" somewhere?

Comment: @SamPeterson What is the line number that the error is occurring at? What is the code at that line number?

Comment: Line 47. The same if statement. Would it help if I uploaded the whole shopping cart php file?

Comment: @SamPeterson If you check through the `$_POST` array, it does not have data about the HTML element besides the `value` that is submitted. So you would not be able to determine if data `$_POST`ed came from a 'submit' button or a 'checkbox' unless you knew what the `name` attribute was.